# Processing nodes in circuit based digraph with cycles for audio DSP

Tags: algorithm, audio, data-structures

For an audio processing chain (like [Propellerheads' Reason](https://www.propellerheads.se/products/reason/index.cfm?fuseaction=get_article&article=features_creative_flow)), I'm developing a circuit of nodes which communicate with each other in an environment where there may be loops (shown below).

Audio devices (nodes) are processed in batches of 64 audio frames, and in the ideal situation, communication propagates within a single batch. Unfortunately feedback loops can be created, which causes a delay in the chain.

**I am looking for the best type of algorithm to consistently minimize feedback loops?**

In my system, a cycle leads to at least one audio device having to be a "feedback node" (shown below), which means its "feedback input" cannot be processed within the same batch.

[image: Digraph]

An example of feedback can be seen in the following processing schedule:

- D -> A
- A -> B
- B -> C
- C -> 'D

In this case the output from C to D has to be processed on the next batch.

Below is an example of an inefficient processing schedule which results in two feedback loops:

- A -> B
- B -> C
- C -> D
- D -> E, 'A
- E -> F
- F -> G
- G -> 'D

Here the output from G to D, and D to A must be processed on the next batch. This means that the output from G reaches A after 2 batches, compared to the output from A to D occurring within the same batch.

The most efficient processing schedule begins with D, which results in just one feedback node (D).

**How large can this graph become?**
It's quite common to have 1000 audio devices (for example a song with 30 audio channels, with 30 effects devices connected), though the there are typically 2-4 outputs per device and the circuits aren't incredibly complex. Instead audio devices tend to be connected with localised scopes so circuits (if they do exist) are more likely to be locally confined though I just need to prepare the most efficient node schedule to reduce the number feedbacks.

**A pair of audio devices with two paths (ideally) should not have mismatched feedback nodes between them**
Suppose there are two nodes, M and N, with two separate paths from M to N, there should not be a feedback node on one path but not on the other as this would desynchronise the input to N, which is highly undesired. This aim complicates the algorithm further. But I will examine how Reason behaves (as it might not actually be so complex).

Comment: This isn't entirely clear; are you saying that on every iteration, each node processes its current inputs to produce its next output?  Or something else?  If it's the former, then I'm not sure I see what the issue is here.  If it's the latter, I think you need to define what you mean by "iteration", etc. ;)

Comment: I'll reword it. What happens is that all nodes are processed batch processed (so I'll rename iteration to batch and add a small description)

Comment: @slater: I've just added my question

Comment: Is this just the [feedback vertex set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback_vertex_set) problem (in a directed graph)?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat: Hmm, it does appear to be the feedback vertex set problem since the most efficient ordering is found by picking from the set of minimum feedback set, ... but it might also fit "Tarjan's strongly connected components algorithm" so I will have to investigate

Comment: FVS may be NP-hard, but I wouldn't be at all surprised if your instances could be solved to provable optimality. According to [this survey](http://www2.research.att.com/~mgcr/doc/sfsp-short.ps), there's been some work on both exact algorithms and heuristics (the approximation algorithms per se probably won't provide useful guarantees).

Comment: Does synchronization require the feedback nodes to be present/absent on all paths or for the counts to be the same?

Comment: Just needs the counts to be the same, but I will update the description to give more details about exactly what I am attempting

Answer (score 0):

[This survey](http://www2.research.att.com/~mgcr/doc/sfsp.ps) describes several approaches to feedback set problems but only briefly describes branch and bound. I think that branch and bound is a promising approach, so I'll expand on that description here.

In branch and bound, we explore a search tree consisting of nodes where each vertex is assigned a label 0, 1, or ?. The meaning of ? is that we don't know what label to give yet, and the root node has all vertices labeled ?. The leaves of the search tree have no vertices labeled ?. The children of a node where at least one vertex is labeled ? are determined by choosing an arbitrary vertex labeled ? and letting it be 0 in the left child and 1 in the right. This is branching.

To bound a node, we do something to determine a lower bound (because we're minimizing) on the number of vertices labeled 1 in a solution where each of the ?s is replaced by a 0 or a 1. If this lower bound is no better than the best solution that we have found so far, then there is no need to explore the subtree further. For proving optimality, the best approach, given space, is depth-first search with best-first backtracking. The depth-first search part consists of repeatedly exploring the more promising child (lower lower bound) and putting the other into a priority queue. Then, when we get stuck because we're at a leaf or because the node got pruned, we pull the most promising possibility out of the queue. We stop when the queue is empty.

One very common approach for obtaining bounds is linear programming. Instead of labeling vertices 0 or 1, it turns out that if we allow fractional labels in the interval [0, 1], then we can find a "solution" relatively efficiently. This cost of this solution is no greater than the true optimum, but it's not possible, of course, to have a node be "half feedback". Select one of the vertices with a fractional label (closest to 0.5 is often a good bet) and branch on it.

In fact, this approach is so common that most linear programming solvers provide a convenient interface to it in the form of integer programming. Unfortunately, integer programming won't work directly for us, because the program has too many constraints: one for each simple cycle. (Come to think of it, if there aren't too many simple cycles, then you could use integer programming after all.)

The linear program for feedback vertex set looks like this. The variable `x_v` is the solution label: 0 if `v` is combinatorial, 1 if `v` is feedback, fractional values interpolating between those two possibilities.

```
minimize sum_v x_v (as few feedback vertices as possible)
subject to
for all simple cycles C, sum_{v in C} x_v >= 1 (at least one vertex on each cycle)
for all v, x_v >= 0 (vertices cannot be "negative feedback")
```

You actually want to solve the dual program, which by weak LP duality, lower bounds the optimal solution when feasible.

```
maximize sum_C y_C
subject to
for all vertices v, sum_{C ni v} y_C <= 1
for all C, y_C >= 0
```

The intuitive meaning of this program is as follows. Suppose that we identified disjoint simple cycles. Each of these cycles contains at least one feedback vertex, and these vertices are distinct. This is the fractional analog of that technique (which works on every LP, not just this one; the dual of this LP is the first LP again).

The technique for solving this LP is called column (i.e., variable) generation. Initially, we send it to the solver with no variables. We then interact with the solver repeatedly, getting solutions and adding variables that look useful, until it becomes clear that we've reached an optimum (or stalled). The solver returns corresponding values for `x_v` for all `v` and `y_C` for the `C` that we've told it about. To find another cycle `C'` that we should include, we want `sum_{v in C'} x_v < 1`, preferably much less. Label each arc by the value of `x_v`, where `x_v` is its head. For each vertex, run Dijkstra to find shortest paths, then check whether the arcs into that vertex form a short cycle.

This is complicated slightly by the side constraints imposed by the current node. If a vertex is labeled 0 or 1, then we omit its constraint from the dual and use that label in place of `x_v` in labeling the graph for Dijkstra.

I hope that, when you determine what the side constraints are, we can devise another column generation strategy to deal with them. I'm more confident about that than I would be modifying the combinatorial reduction strategies surveyed.

Comment: Many thanks, I need to implement this to confirm for sure but it seems legit.